# Unable to update to Xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, xcode

When I tried to update to Xcode 8.3, the following happened in App Store (it has been like this for over an hour):

[image]

So it just says "loading" and nothing happens.

What I already tried:

- Mac restart
- Logoff and Login to the App Store

Any ideas?

btw: My Apple membership expires in 5 days - could this be a problem?

Comment: Your Apple Membership has nothing to do with downloading Xcode. Xcode is freely available to anybody - even people who have not paid to be Apple Developers. One thing you might want to try (if possible) is try to download from a different location - if you tried at home, try from work or the other way around.

Comment: have you tried downloading from - https://developer.apple.com/downloads

Comment: Yes - already tried (opens the correct Page - and then nothing happens)

Comment: Delete Xcode from Applications and download from AppStore

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Xcode 8.3 requires macOs Sierra
[release notes Xcode 8](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html)

I was facing the same issue with macOs El Capitan

Comment: Thanks for your answer - The App Store should show an error message, and not just running the spinner for an couple of hours...

Comment: @derdida ;) the spinner was making me crazy until i notice that.

Comment: Great, now I NEED another macbook because Sierra is not compatible with mine just because they don't want it to be. I hate this company so bad.

Comment: @derdida some companies enjoy abusing developers

Comment: @derdida now why would they do that? That would be a logical thing to do :)

Answer (score 6):

Just sign in on developer.apple.com, and go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/, you can find Xcode8.3 there and download. Good luck!

Comment: This worked great for me. I am using Sierra but my laptop is mid-2012 version. App Store wouldn't udpate it for me, so manually downloaded via the link provided.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's [a challenging way](https://github.com/michalzelinka/Xcode83onElCapitan) to modify and run it if you get it from the Developers portal. :) Not as your primary Xcode instance, but experiments are possible. :))

Comment: Thanks for the information. Maybe useful for someone who want to stay on El Capitan

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded my mid-2012 mac book pro to Sierra. But still was stuck with spinner.

This helped solve it. - ([link to the apple discussion forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7297094?tstart=0))

"Going to Applications in Finder and moving Xcode to the trash bin fixed the problem for me. As soon as I entered in my password to confirm moving Xcode to the trash, the App Store prompted me on whether or not I wanted to cancel the update or delete the app. I opted to delete Xcode, and the App Store immediately began downloading the update."

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Apple Developer account, download the latest xcode directly from here: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.3/Xcode_8.3.xip.

Note: if you are unable to install the latest OS, at this time: OSSierra, then you will not be able to be able to install Xcode 8.3 to my knowledge (I was not able to.  I had to get a new computer, which I had to do).

Answer (score 0):

wait for 8-10 minutes without pressing pause or cancel or so.
just wait. and it will start while you eating popcorn.

even though it not started to update and stuck at 0kb, the term you have to focus is "patience".

Answer (score -1):

Just go to App Store and click on Store -> Check for Unfinished Downloads.

Comment: Already tried - but there is no download visible. It is not downloading anything, just waiting. Never seen that before

Comment: Do this:

    1. Run this command from Terminal: `defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true && killall App\ Store`.
    2. Go to the the App Store debug menu and reveal the download folder. You can delete the whole thing from Finder.
    Log out and back in to your Mac.
    Empty the trash.