# Can I delete entire developer folder under Library

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to update my Xcode 8.2 to Xcode 9. I upgraded my OS to macOs High Sierra 10.13. Then I went to Mac App Store and tried downloading it and the update button keeps spinning for infinity. I searched google and stackoverflow and apparently this is a known bug going back ages. One of the solution suggested that I should delete Xcode application and then try the download/update button again in App Store.

See Here [Unable to update to Xcode 8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065475/unable-to-update-to-xcode-8-3)

So, if I am going to completely remove Xcode application from my computer then I was thinking I should cleanup my comp and remove unnecessary Xcode files that I don't need and they will be recreated upon a new install. These are huge folders and looks like related to my Xcode development activities. Can I safely delete them?

- Can I delete the entire ~\library\Developer folder?
  [image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To answer my own question YES its completely safe to delete `~/Library/Developer` folder if you plan to completely remove your existing Xcode and install a new version. Actually its highly recommended you do so. Everything worked and all projects compile.

The newly created one was only 772MB. Come on Apple! What a waste of space that was.

```
MacBookPro2012:Library$ du -sh Developer
722M    Developer
```

Comment: I copied only the required simulator files from the old Developer folder to the newer one to avoid redownloading it at `Developer/CoreSimulators/Devices/....`. You may check the folder name of required simulators by opening `Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Simulators` and then click on the required simulator and check for `identifier`. I was able to work on the existing project without a problem and Developer folder was just 3GB for 2 simulators from 23GB. That's huge for a 128GB Mac!